# why 1st epoch takes a lot of time in training neural network model?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a doubt about the training my neural network, so my first epoch takes the most time, for example right now first epoch takes around 50 mins while subsequent epoch takes only 2 mins, why is it the case?

where should I look for to resolve this if its the problem?

Here is the model code for the reference :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(2, (3,3,3), padding = 'same', input_shape= [num_of_frame, 
          img_rows,img_cols, img_channels] ))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(64, (3,3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

I am using adam for optimizer and batch size is 30, running it on Google Colab.

Here is the code for training and validation :

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1, 
                    callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_data=val_generator, 
                    validation_steps=validation_steps, class_weight=None, workers=1, initial_epoch=0)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add Colab link? In the above code-block every things seem just fine.

Comment: The code you added is the model, not the actual training process. Add it.

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out, as my training code is merged with generator, the overall time was more. Once I called next() manually on my datagenerator, All epochs started behaving in similar way.